# WHERE clause not matching values in Geode

Tags: apache, geode

Values aren't considered a match in Geode query. Wondering if the values aren't being used correctly at all, as I can't do any sort of WHERE successfully.

I have tried inputting both keys and values with no quotes, with single quotes(') and with double quotes ("). I am not using complex classes, so everything is a java.lang.String by default.

For example, I have this entry in my "amount" region:

```
put --key=(“p7”) --value=(356.08) --region=amount
```

Querying

```
query --query="SELECT * FROM /amount"
```

shows that key/value pair, among others, in the region. 
However, when I query

```
query --query="SELECT * FROM /amount WHERE /amount.entries.value > 100"
```

I am getting a result: true, and no rows (so I know the query is valid)

I have been banging my head against this for 2 days now and I don't understand what's so wrong with what should be a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

The `put` command assumes that both the `key` and `value` are of type `java.lang.String`, that's why the comparison is *silently failing* and not returning any results. You should use the `--key-class` and `--value-class` parameters to customise the actual type (see [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/18/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/put.html) for further details).

As an example, the following set of commands achieves what you want:

```
gfsh>create region --name=amount --type=REPLICATE
Member  | Status
------- | -------------------------------------
server1 | Region "/amount" created on "server1"


gfsh>query --query="<TRACE> SELECT * FROM /amount"
Result      : true
Limit       : 100
Rows        : 0
Query Trace : Query Executed in 0.395477 ms; indexesUsed(0)


gfsh>put --key="key1" --value="356" --region=/amount --value-class=java.lang.Long
Result      : true
Key Class   : java.lang.String
Key         : key1
Value Class : java.lang.Long
Old Value   : null


gfsh>query --query="<TRACE> SELECT * FROM /amount.values"
Result      : true
Limit       : 100
Rows        : 1
Query Trace : Query Executed in 0.468153 ms; indexesUsed(0)

Result
------
356


gfsh>query --query="<TRACE> SELECT * FROM /amount.values v WHERE v > 100"
Result      : true
Limit       : 100
Rows        : 1
Query Trace : Query Executed in 0.85026 ms; indexesUsed(0)

Result
------
356
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.